# Record and play video in portrait

Tags: android, video-recording

Hi guys i have been trying to record the video in portrait mode and play it back after uploading to the AWS S3. But the video always plays in the landscape mode ie. the video is rotated by 90 degree clockwise. I then tried to record the video by setting the landscape orientation to the recording activity still the same thing happens. While recording with portrait i used usepreviewdisplay method to rotate the preview by 90 degree and i know that it doesn't affect the recording. But when the orientationhint to 270 i was able to play the video in portrait on latest devices with android 4.0 +, but not with other version. Also i need to play the same video on the web portal and we are using [jw player](http://www.longtailvideo.com/) for playing the videos on the web. Also i need to play the same video on iOS to. So how can i acheive this. Any help or ideas would be appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

`File file = new File(path, filename);
mrec = new MediaRecorder(); mCamera.lock(); mCamera.unlock(); mrec.setCamera(mCamera); mrec.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA); mrec.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC); mrec.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4); mrec.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.MPEG_4_SP); mrec.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB); 
mrec.setVideoSize(320, 240); 
mrec.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder.getSurface()); mrec.setOutputFile(path + filename); mrec.prepare();`

Comment: Hi, I hope you solved the issue please share how?

Comment: @ErmaIsabel I recorded the video on Landscape orientation(Device) with the resolution of 176 x 144. While recording with this resolution only, it worked well with jw player in all the browsers, increasing resolution resulted in orientation problem on web browser players.